# how to get the request uri inside active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have polymorphic models:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true  
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end
```

In order to get my activeadmin model to work with both parents (Service and Product) I need to do something like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Picture do
  def who_do_i_belong_to?
    uri = how_to_get_uri?
    if uri.match(/products/) 
      :product
    else
      :service
    end
  end

  belongs_to  who_do_i_belong_to?
end
```

The workaround seems to work. I only miss how to get the url/uri from inside the who_do_i_belong_to? method.

```
controller.controller_name # "admin/services", so it is not useful.
```

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: What do you ultimately want to achieve? For example, are you trying to render an index of pictures, where each picture is customized depending on its association (i.e. `:product` or `:service`)?

Comment: The models work fine. I only want to be able to CRUD pictures for product and service via ActiveAdmin /admin/products/1/images and /admin/services/1/images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have CRUD for your polymorphic nested resources (`products/pictures` and `services/pictures`), your application needs to have routes like `/admin/products/:id/images` and `/admin/services/:id/images`. The problem is that when you use `belongs_to :parent` in a `register` block, active_admin will only generate one nested route `admin/parents/:id/child`, whereas you need two. Furthermore, `:parent` can't be determine by the current url, because the call `belongs_to :parent` itself is used to create the current url (the resource path).

To get around this, you can define the routes yourself in configs.rb

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :services do
    resources :pictures
  end

  resources :products do
    resources :pictures
  end
end
```

and tell active_admin to use these routes by writing `controller.belongs_to :service, :product, polymorphic: true` in your `register` block for `Picture`.

Source: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1183

Answer (score 1):

Requesting uri from inside a model is against MVC design. Your method should be in your application controller. And when you want to register a picture, your current controller should tell the model what it is.

Comment: I am not trying to get the url from inside the model. I am trying to get it from inside ActiveAdmin, which holds the controller.

Comment: Something like `url_for` or `request.path` then?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `#imageable_type` to find out which the parent model is.

For example:

```
Image.find(1).imageable_type # => "Product"
```

Comment: It does not work. I have no access to the id inside who_do_i_belong_to? method. Besides, it would not work for creating pictures, since the imageable_type should be persisted.

Comment: Imageable_type is a also column in your database, it's actually in the polymorphic model, check it out. So it is persisted and you query any image object for it's imageable_type.